# Loop through json array in string python

Tags: python, json

I have a string and I created a JSON array which contains strings and values:

```
amount = 0
a = "asaf,almog,arnon,elbar"
values_li={'asaf':'1','almog':'6','elbar':'2'}
```

How can I create a loop that will search all items on `values_li` in `a` and for each item it will find it will do

```
amount = amount + value(the value that found from value_li in a)
```

I tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
for k,v in values_li.items():
    if k in a:
        amount = amount + v
```

Comment: `ammount += int(v)`, you're trying to append a string. It would also be great if you in the future tell us why it isn't working by adding a traceback or description of the problem, not just what you want to achieve. I'm guessing tho that you're getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. Hence my first part of my comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What happens instead of what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's working.
I figure out my problem.
v is a string and I tried to do math with a string so I had to convert v to an int

```
amount = amount + int(v)
```

Now It's working :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful using:

```
if k in a:
```

`a` is the string: `"asaf,almog,arnon,elbar"` not a list. This means that:

`"bar" in a # == True`
`"as" in a # == True`

..etc Which is probably not what you want.

You should consider splitting it into an array, then you'll only get complete matches. With that you can simply use:

```
a = "asaf,almog,arnon,elbar".split(',')
values_li={'asaf':'1','almog':'6','elbar':'2'}

amount = sum([int(values_li[k]) for k in a if k in values_li])
# 9
```

Answer (score 0):

`collections.Counter()` is your friend:

```
from collections import Counter
a = "asaf,almog,arnon,elbar"
values_li = Counter({'asaf':1,'almog':6,'elbar':2})
values_li.update(a.split(','))
values_li
```

That will result in:

```
Counter({'almog': 7, 'elbar': 3, 'asaf': 2, 'arnon': 1})
```

And if you want the sum of all values in `values_li`, you can simply do:

```
sum(values_li.values())
```

Which will result in `13`, for the key/value pairs in your example.